# React: How do I assign an element to a variable?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to read a value with an if statement and return an element, something like:

```
  let visibilityText = '';

  if (visibility === 'private') {
    let visibilityText = (
      <span>Private</span>
    );
  } else {
    let visibilityText = (
      <span>Public</span>
    );
  }
```

And in my `return()` I've added:

```
{visibilityText}
```

But nothing shows at all.

Would anyone know what I need to do?

Comment: have you tried    let visibilityText: any =  <span>Public</span>;      ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

shouldn't it be without 'let'? I think you redeclare the variable

```
let visibilityText = '';

  if (visibility === 'private') {
    visibilityText = (
      <span>Private</span>
    );
  } else {
    visibilityText = (
      <span>Public</span>
    );
  }
```